# In Karate DSL, calling a javascript file returns java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: javascript, node.js, karate

I have a javascript file I want to call. contents are below. When I tried calling the file, I keep getting a "no variable found with name: response" even though there is clearly a variable defined. The file executes fine within command-line using node so the javascript function is valid. Any thoughts? I attached the error message in a screenshot.

Javascript content in snippet below.

Karate script:

Scenario: Call JavaScript:

```
    * def sample = read('classpath:reusable/gen-data.js')

    * print someValue
```

```js
function createTestData(sampleJson, fieldsToChange, numRecords) {
    var testData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
        var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sampleJson));

        fieldsToChange.forEach(function(fieldToChange) {
            copy[fieldToChange] = copy[fieldToChange] + i;
        });

        testData.push(copy);
    }



    return {content: testData};
}

var testData = {

  "country": "US",
  "taskStatusCode" : "Closed",
  "facilityCode" : "US_203532",

};

function getTestData() {

  String testData = JSON.stringify(createTestData(testData, ["taskStatusCode", "facilityCode"], 1), null, 1);

  console.log("all done getTestData()");
  console.log("test data: \n" + testData);

  return testData;
};


console.log("calling getTestData()");
getTestData();
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, I can't help here as this is all very confusing. I have to say you seem to be un-necessary complicating things with JS. don't use JS unless you really truly have to. all  the best.

Comment: I truly had to use JS in the above scenario. Ended up switching to java and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround was to use java instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

I think this error is thrown when the JavaScript is not correct. For example in my case this JS file:

```
/* Set the custom authentication header */
function fn() {
    var authToken = karate.get('authToken');
    var out = {};
    out['Auth-Token'] = authToken
    return out;
}
```

This file will produce the "no variable found with name: response".

The reason is because "the right-hand-side (or contents of the *.js file if applicable) should begin with the function keyword." according to the karate docs ([link](https://github.com/intuit/karate#javascript-functions)).

Now by moving the comment and making the function keyword the first bit of text it works as expected:

```
function fn() {
/* Set the custom authentication header */
    var authToken = karate.get('authToken');
    var out = {};
    out['Auth-Token'] = authToken
    return out;
}
```

In the OP, the function keyword is the first thing in the file, but there is javascript outside the original function -- which I don't think is legal for karate syntax. In other words, everything has to be in the outer function.